# about overflow in css with floated elements

Tags: css, overflow

when you use overflow:hidden to the main wrapper that are contain floated element how does overflow fix the flow of floated element

```
<html>
 when you use overflow:hidden to the main wrapper that are contain floated element how        does overflow fix the flow of floated element
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get. Can you make fiddle? or produce yur code?

Comment: when you wrap floated element to a container the container will collapse, but if you give a container overflow:hidden it will fix the collapsing problem, my question is how does it fix this problem

Comment: overflow:hidden is the problem means you can give overflow:scroll or something.

Comment: but how does it fix the float problem

Answer (score 0):

Giving `overflow:hidden` to an element creates a Block Formatting Context(BFC) also known as "flow root".

One of the properties of BFC is float containment i.e. all floated elements within the div to which you give `overflow:hidden` are contained.

Also since the BFC is a part of the normal flow of the document, there is no need for clearing.